# Laravel issue with Patchwork UTF8

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I have just pulled a remote Laravel project from Github and ran composer install to create the vendor folder.

However, this returns an error in the terminal:

```
  [RuntimeException]
```

Could not scan for classes inside "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imperialnet/ve
  ndor/patchwork/utf8/src/Normalizer.php" which does not appear to be a file
  nor a folder

And this error in the error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
```

Looking in Vendor > patchwork > utf8 there is no SRC folder? What is going with composer or ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Deleting the vendor folder and the composer.lock file and then running `composer install` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may write in console: composer update --dev